# Incorrect Encoding Causing Problems with DB Query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, encoding

It's late and my caffeine IV is running low so my mind is mush and I'm having problems finding a solution to what I think is a simple encoding problem (which I have almost no experience dealing with).

I have a DB using EF6 Code First and everything seems to work well until I copy some text from a website forum contained within a codeblock.  I checked the header and it's supposedly encoded in UTF-8.

I essentially take this text, split it to an array of strings and check the DB for a record matching the string in each line.  Everything was going well until I hit a problem with a string "Magnеtic" not matching up to anything in my DB table yet when I went into the SQLMS and queried the table with LIKE '%Magnеtic%' I got a result.

I dropped the text from the website into Notepad++ with the text from the DB query and saw that they look equal:

```
Magnеtic
Magnеtic
```

Then, I changed the encoding to ANSI and it showed:

```
Magnetic   <--From DB
MagnÐµtic  <--From website
```

A tiny light bulb went on in my head but my attempts to remedy this issue has failed.

I've tried using various methods but I think it's my fried brain attacking the problem with the wrong tools:

```
string.compare(a, b) == 0
string.equals(a, b)
string.ToUpperInvariant()
```

and probably a few others that I can't remember.

So now you know what my issue is and I feel this is such a simple problem to fix but, like I said, I'm fried and now need some community help.

I'm not a professional coder, more a hobbyist so I may not be using best practices or advanced techniques to do some things.

Edit:
Today I did some more searching and found a couple of methods that didn't work.

```
private string RemoveAccent(string txt)
{
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes(txt);
     return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
```

This one appears to remove the accented characters of the Cyrillic encoding.  The result wasn't as expected but it DID have an effect.
Results:

```
Magn?tic <- Computer interpretation
Magnetic <- Visual representation
```

I also tried:

```
private string RemoveAccent2(string txt)
{
    char[] toReplace = "àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ äëïöüÄËÏÖÜ âêîôûÂÊÎÔÛ áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚðÐýÝ ãñõÃÑÕšŠžŽçÇåÅøØ".ToCharArray();
    char[] replaceChars = "aeiouAEIOU aeiouAEIOU aeiouAEIOU aeiouAEIOUdDyY anoANOsSzZcCaAoO".ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < toReplace.Count(); i++)
    {
        txt = txt.Replace(toReplace[i], replaceChars[i]);
    }
    return txt;
}
```

This method didn't provide any changes.

Answer (score 0):

What can help in these cases is to copy-paste the character into google. In this case, the results point to [the Wikipedia article about the letter Ye in Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_%28Cyrillic%29), which looks exactly like E in the Latin alphabet, but has different encoding in Unicode.

This means the results you're getting are correct: the string “Magnеtic” looks exactly the same as “Magnetic” (at least using common fonts), but it's actually a different string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @svick.  So, if I'm getting two visually identical strings yet the computer is interpreting them as different, how can I normalize all text that comes in so that I can compare what I _visually_ see rather than what the computer interprets?

Comment: @Josh I don't think there's anything like that, especially since different fonts could behave differently.